# Cannot get my datatables drill down to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, nested, html-table

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var anOpen = [];
var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();

$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

    console.log("clicked|" + i);

    if (i == -1) {
        var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
        $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
        anOpen.push(nTr);
        console.log("open");
    }
    else {
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        anOpen.splice( i, 1 );
        console.log("closed");
    }
});

function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
    var oData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    var sOut =
'<div class="innerDetails">' +
  '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>' + 'hi' + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Browser:</td><td>' + 'hi' + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Platform:</td><td>' + 'hi' + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Version:</td><td>' + 'hi' + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Grade:</td><td>' + 'hi' + '</td></tr>' +
  '</table>' +
'</div>';
    return sOut;
}
```

Just gave a section of it, When i click on the row it does trigger the if (i==-1) and then when i click again it triggers the else and works back and forth the problem is that i cannot get anything to display. The table just sits and new opens another table below it like it should. No errors in the console just the proper console logs.

Comment: Is nTr the correct value?  You're doing this.parentNode, but shouldn't this already be the tr?

Comment: That was the problem...thank you so much.